# Set of values of $a$ for which function always increases

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

If the set of all values of the parameter $a$ for which the function $$f(x)=\sin (2x)-8(a+1) \sin x+(4a^2+8a-14)x$$ increases for all $x \in R$ and has no critical point for all $x \in R$ is $(- \infty, m- \sqrt n) \cup (\sqrt n, \infty)$, then find the value of $m^2+n^2$ (where $m,n$ are prime numbers).

After finding $f'(x)$, we need to set $f'(x)>0$ but I am not having any clue how to extract condition on $a$? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all $a$ such that $f(x)=\sin2x-8(a+1)\sin x+(4a^2+8a-14)x$ is increasing and has no critical points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224241/finding-all-a-such-that-fx-sin2x-8a1-sin-x4a28a-14x-is-increasing)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the derivative

$$f'(x) = 2\cos(2x) - 8(a+1)\cos x + (4a^2 + 8a -14)$$

Now both $\cos (2x)$ and $\cos x$ oscillate between $-1$ to $1$. Thus assuming $a \ge -1$,

$$-2 - 8(a+1) + 4a^2 + 8a - 14 \le f'(x) \le 2 + 8(a+1) + 4a^2 + 8a - 14$$

$$4a^2  - 24 \le f'(x) \le 4a^2 + 16a - 4$$

$$4(a^2  - 6) \le f'(x) \le 4(a^2 + 4a - 1)$$

Then $a > \sqrt{6}$ implies $0 < 4(a^2 - 6) \le f'(x)$.

On the other hand, if $a < 1$,

$$-2 + 8(a+1) + 4a^2 + 8a - 14 \le f'(x) \le 2 - 8(a+1) + 4a^2 + 8a - 14$$

$$4a^2 + 16a - 8 \le f'(x) \le 4a^2 - 20$$

$$4(a^2 + 4a - 2) \le f'(x) \le 4(a^2 - 5)$$

Then $a < -2 - \sqrt{6}$ implies $0 < 4(a^2 + 4a - 2) \le f'(x)$.

Therefore $a \in (-\infty,-2-\sqrt{6})\cup(\sqrt{6},\infty)$ makes the derivative positive for all $x$, which means the function is strictly increasing and has no critical points.

---

This seems to match what they are after except that $6$ isn't prime. Did I make an error somewhere?

Comment: Answer given is 29

Comment: That would mean $m$ and $n$ are $2$ and $5$, but that doesn't match with the function given. I'm guessing it's a mistake. They probably changed the problem and forgot about the prime part of the statement.