# Find the values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)=\sin (2x)-8(a+1) \sin x+(4a^2+8a-14)x$ increases for all $x\in R$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Find the values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)=\sin (2x)-8(a+1) \sin x+(4a^2+8a-14)x$ increases for all $x\in R$ and has no critical points.

For increasing function, $$f'(x)\gt0\\2\cos(2x) - 8(a+1)\cos x + (4a^2 + 8a -14)\gt0$$

Using $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1$, $$4\cos^2x-8(a+1)\cos x+4a^2+8a-16\gt0\\\cos^2x-2(a+1)\cos x+a^2+2a-4\gt0\\(\cos x-(a+1))^2-5\gt0\\(\cos x-a-1+\sqrt5)(\cos x-a-1-\sqrt5)\gt0\\\cos x\lt a+1-\sqrt5 \text{ or }\cos x\gt a+1+\sqrt5$$

Now, I know that $\cos x$ lies between $-1$ and $1$. Not able to use that to solve the inequality.

Also, the same question has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918375/set-of-values-of-a-for-which-function-always-increases), but the approach is different. Also, the final answer posted there is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done! Each of the two inequalities has to be true **for all** $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let us consider the first situation:
$$\text{cos} \ x<a+1-\sqrt{5} , \ (\forall) \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Since the maximum value of $\text{cos} \ x$ is $1$ we get that $$1<a+1-\sqrt{5} \iff \sqrt{5} <a$$

For the second case:
$$\text{cos} \ x>a+1+\sqrt{5} , \ (\forall) \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Since the minimum value of $\text{cos} \ x$ is $-1$ we get that $$-1>a+1+\sqrt{5} \iff -2-\sqrt{5} >a$$
Thus, $$a \in (-\infty,-2-\sqrt{5}) \cup (\sqrt{5}, \infty)$$

Comment: I got the same answer! :)

Comment: Any chance you could make number line and show how the inequality is working? Because I am having tough time understanding whether to use $\lt$ sign or $\gt$ and whether to use $-1$ or $+1$.

Comment: So you don't understand why $\text{cos} \ x <a+1-\sqrt{5}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $1<a+1-\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: If $\cos x\lt\alpha$, I would assume $\alpha$ should be less than $1$ because if $\alpha$ comes out to be $2$ that may imply $\cos x$ can be $1.5$ too which is not true. Or, if $\cos x\lt\alpha$, I would assume $\alpha$ should be greater than $-1$.

Comment: Wait, you are searching for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{cos} \ x < \alpha$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Why $\alpha = 2$ or $\alpha=3$, or $\alpha = 100$ are not good? Is it true that $\text{cos} \ x <2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Of course it is! So $\alpha=2$ is a solution!

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By your work we need $$\cos^2x-2(a+1)\cos x+a^2+2a-4>0.$$

We have three cases:

1. $a+1>0$. In this case we need $$1^2-2(a+1)\cdot1+a^2+2a-4>0.$$
2. $a+1<-1$. In this case we need $$(-1)^2-2(a+1)\cdot(-1)+a^2+2a-4>0.$$
3. $$(a+1)^2-(a^2+2a-4)<0.$$
   Can you end it now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why are we taking $\cos x=1$ in the first case and $\cos x=-1$ in the second?

Comment: @aarbee  Yes, of course. Draw the parabola in theses cases.