# Finding all $a$ such that $f(x)=\sin2x-8(a+1)\sin x+(4a^2+8a-14)x$ is increasing and has no critical points

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, quadratics

> Find the set of all values of the parameter $a$ for which the function, $$f(x)=\sin\left(2x\right)-8\left(a+1\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\left(4a^2+8a-14\right)x$$
> increases for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and has no critical points for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

Obviously, the first thing I did was to find the derivative of this function and simplify it a bit and I got:

$$f'(x)=4\left(\;\cos^2x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+\left(a^2+2a-4\right)\;\right)$$
But now how do I proceed further, had it been a simple quadratic in $x$. I would've calculated $D<0$ but this is a quadratic in $\cos x$. Can I do the same here? Why or why not? How should I go ahead?

Not just this, there are many instances where the quadratic is not in x, but in expressions like $e^{x}$. Is there any general approach to solving these quadratics for things like no solutions etc-

Comment: $f'(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: I edited it, my bad, it should be correct now.

Comment: Yup... Here you get a quadratic in cosine and you may get a quadratic on $e^x$ as well. But there's always a way in which you can proceed... I mean, try completing square in cosine and you will get the required solutions for "a"

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai thank you, this works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=4(\cos^{2}x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+\left(a^{2}+2a-4\right))$$
We need to find *a* for which f(x) is increasing, which means f'(x)>0.

Now,

$$4(\cos^{2}x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+\left(a^{2}+2a-4\right))>0$$

$$\cos^{2}x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+\left(a^{2}+2a-4\right)>0$$

$$(\cos^{2}x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+a^{2}+2a+1)>5$$

$$((\cos x -(a+1))^2>5$$

$\cos x -(a+1)>√5$ or $\cos x-(a+1)<-√5$

$$a<\cos x-1-√5$$ or $$a>\cos x-1+√5$$

Hence, $a<-2-√5$ or $a>√5$.

Comment: But hey Wait!... These are values of a for which f(x) is increasing... Since we asked for which there are no critical points, you have to see where f(x) had critical points and remove them from the solution set. You will get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since I got the answer:
To solve:

$f'\left(x\right)>0$
i.e. $f'(x)=4\left(\;\cos^2x-2\left(a+1\right)\cos x+\left(a^2+2a-4\right)\;\right)$ $>0$

Completing the square:
$4(\left[\cos x-\left(a+1\right)\right]^{2}-5)>0$

Solving this, considering the critical cases according to what value $\cos x$ takes and final answer is:

$a \in \left(-\infty,-2-\sqrt{5}\right)\cup\left(\sqrt{5},\infty\right)$

Answer (score 1):

A [preliminary exploration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%282+a%5E2+-+4+%28a+%2B+1%29+cos%28x%29+%2B+4+a+%2B+cos%282+x%29+-+7%29%3E0) indicates that the answer is $a\in(-\infty,p)\cup(q,\infty),$ where $p≈−4.25,q≈2.25.$

---

Here's the full solution. We want: $$\forall x\in\mathbb R\quad f'(x)>0.$$

Let $y=\cos x.$ Then we want: $$\forall y\in[-1,1]\quad y^2-2(a+1)y+(a^2+2a-4)>0.$$
This function in $y$ opens upwards ($y^2$ has positive coefficient) and has two $x-$intercepts (discriminant is $5>0$). So, we want either its right $x-$intercept to be less than $-1$ or its left $x-$intercept to be greater than $1:$ $$a+1+\sqrt5<-1 \quad\text{or}\quad a+1-\sqrt5>1\\
a\in(-\infty,-2-\sqrt5)\cup(\sqrt5,\infty).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here in as we need to find the parameter $[a]$ if $[f(x) = \sin 2x - 8(a + 1)\sin x + (4{a^2} + 8a - 14)x]$ increases for all $[x \in R]$ and has no critical points for all $[x \in R]$ which means $[f'(x) \geqslant 0]$ because the function increases but it is mentioned that there are no critical points for all $[x \in R]$ so we need to find $[f'(x){\text{ > }}0]$ only as if there is no critical point then $[f'(x) \ne 0]$ and simplify the functions by differentiating.

> If you still can't solve it [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-fxsin-2x8a1sin-x4a28a14x-increases-for-all-xin-r-and-has-no-critical-points-for/) is the answer.

Comment: I know these steps already, I just don't know how I do proceed to solve this quadratic inequality involving trig and parameters!  And solution on the website is different from the answer key that I have.